# How can the Facebook API be used to invite friends to your Fan page in batch?

Tags: facebook

On Facebook you can invite your Facebook friends to your Facebook fan page, but this has to be done manually selecting each one and clicking to invite them. If you have several thousand Facebook friends you want to invite to "Like" your fan page that's a huge manual effort.

Can this be accomplished in batch through the Facebook API?

Comment: Linked https://stackoverflow.com/q/43533672/623519