# Is there Facebook api for "Invite People Who Like This Post to Like Your Page"?

Tags: facebook

Is there facebook APIs for inviting People to like page who liked Posts.

Facebook has secret feature to invite people to like page who liked post -
 like this one -> https://authenticstorytelling.net/facebook-how-to-invite-people-who-liked-your-facebook-posts-to-your-facebook-page/

I wonder if there's any API for developer to do same job. It is tedious and time consuming to go one by one.

Comment: No there is no API

Comment: Would also be tedious and time consuming to deal with this kind of *king spam ... from a user perspective.

Answer (score 1):

There are already different extensions in a market. Just search in Chrome, example: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/invite-fans-in-facebook-p/afcmdobhpmaihelfkfaanjedndihhlib
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-fan-inviter-cust/nadkillaoaocaambipdgoookeaghjeik